# Get Interval Night and Day per Day between two dates

Tags: php, date

I am creating an algorithm that must return two intervals between two dates:

```
$interval_day (between 6am and 9pm)
$interval_night (between 9pm and 6am)
```

Currently, I managed to have the overall interval between these two dates for the day. However, I now need a daytime interval and a nighttime interval for the day.

Here is the code I have done to get the interval per day between two dates:

```
foreach($period as $p => $v){
            $day = $v->format('Y-m-d');
            $interval = 0;
                foreach($rotations as $rotation){
                    // Get the day of each dates
                    $date_start = explode(" ", $rotation['date_start'])[0];
                    $date_end = explode(" ", $rotation['date_end'])[0];
                    if($date_start == $date_end){
                        // += interval between the two dates
                        $interval += strtotime($rotation['date_end']) - strtotime($rotation['date_start']);
                    }else if($date_start == $day){
                        // += interval between the start date and midnight
                        $interval += strtotime($day." 23:59:59") - strtotime($rotation['date_end']);
                    }else if($date_end == $day){
                        // += interval between midnight and the end date
                        $interval += strtotime($rotation['date_end']) - strtotime($day." 00:00:00");
                    }
                }
}
```

I hope it's clear for you

What I want now is to get 2 intervals instead of one :

- 1 interval for dates between 6 am and 9 pm as `$interval_day`
- 1 interval for dates between 9 pm and 6 am as `$interval_night`

For exemple:

`rotation['date_start'] = 27/07/2018 21:00:00
rotation['date_end'] = 28/07/2018 02:00:00`

then

- 27/07/2018 :

`$interval_day = 00:00:00` and `$interval_night = 03:00:00`

- 28/07/2018 :

`$interval_day = 00:00:00` and `$interval_night = 02:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each day you have to compute 3 overlappings:

1. overlapping between the interval [`date_start time_start`,
   `date_end time_end`] for the given day and the interval [`date_start 06:00:00`, `date_end 21:00:00`]
2. overlapping between the interval [`date_start time_start`, `date_end time_end`] for the given day and the interval [`date_start 00:00:00`, `date_end 06:00:00`]
3. overlapping between the interval [`date_start time_start`, `date_end time_end`) for the given day and the interval [`date_start 21:00:00`, `date_end 23:59:59`]

To do that, use the following formula:

```
overlap = MAX(0,end_1 - start_1 - MAX(0,end_1 - end_2) - MAX(0,start_2 - start_1))
```

The formula needs integers - i.e. UNIX timestamps.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I never used overlapping functions so I don't understand your formula. I'm looking for more infos on the internet. Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, you need the amount of time which is sitting simultaneously inside the given day and inside the `interval_day` (or `interval_night`) - which means how much `interval_day` overlaps the given day. The formula is very simple if you draw on paper one of the intervals and then draw the other inside the first. If you subtract the left and right segments from the duration of the 1st interval - you will get the amount of overlapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot I understood